# Join Group By Columns Vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple *group by* queries that I need to be join horizontally. Here is what I have.

[image]

Here is what I need. Is this doable?

[image]

```
select 
    Group, 
    Count([Total # Records]
from table 

select 
    Group, 
    Count([Total # Records]
from table 
where 
[Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -60, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is script of the solution I ultimately used. A full working copy and sample databae can be found at [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50e5f2870069f08d4fb7d7f43d88779e)

[image]

```
 ;with table1CTE 
as
(   
    select 
        [Groups], 
        sum([total # records]) as [total # records]
    from 
        tbl1
where 
    [Groups] 
in 
    (
        select 
            [groups]    
        from 
        (
        select  
            [groups],
            [total # records]
        from 
            tbl1
        ) as sourceTbl1
        pivot
        (sum ([total # records])
            for [groups]
            in
            ([Central Business],
            [Venture Capital])
        ) as pvt
    )
    group by [groups]
),--table1CTE 
table2CTE  as
(
    select 
        [Groups], 
        sum([No Action Over 60 Days]) as [No Action Over 60 Days]
    from 
        tbl2
where 
    [Groups] 
in 
    (
        select 
            [groups]    
        from 
    (
        select  
            [groups],
            [No Action Over 60 Days]
        from 
            tbl1
    ) as sourceTbl1
        pivot
        (sum ([No Action Over 60 Days])
            for [groups]
            in
            ([Central Business],
            [Venture Capital])
        ) as pvt
    )
    group by [groups]
)--table2CTE 
select 
    table1CTE.groups, 
    table1CTE.[total # records], 
    table2CTE.[No Action Over 60 Days]

from table1CTE  left join table2CTE on table1CTE.[Groups] = table2CTE.[Groups]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select Group, Count([Total # Records]),
       sum(case when [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -60, getdate() then 1 else 0 end)
from table 
group by group;
```

Comment: @user716255 . . . Is there a reason you didn't use this method and unaccepted this answer?  It seems much simpler than using `pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional aggregation using `COUNT` aggregate function as follows:

```
select group, 
       count([Total # Records]),
       count(case when [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -60, getdate()) then 1 end)
from table 
group by group;
```

`COUNT` will ignore the null values produced by the conditions so it will give count of the records which fulfills the condition.